# Getting Issue in Java Connecting SP-API Using Java SDK sellingpartner-api-aa-java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazonsellercentral

I have followed all the steps to generate SDK and .jar files.  . I have included the external jar into my project and stepping through the documentation "[Connecting to the Selling Partner API using a generated Java SDK https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api-using-a-generated-java-sdk

Step 1:

```
AWSAuthenticationCredentials awsAuthenticationCredentials=AWSAuthenticationCredentials.builder()
.accessKeyId("myAccessKeyId")
.secretKey("mySecretId")
.region("us-east-1")
.build();
```

Step 2:

```
AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider=AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider.builder()
.roleArn("myroleARN")
.roleSessionName("myrolesessioname")
.build();
```

Step 3:

```
LWAAuthorizationCredentials lwaAuthorizationCredentials = LWAAuthorizationCredentials.builder()
.clientId("myClientId")
.clientSecret("myClientSecret")
.refreshToken("Aztr|...")
.endpoint("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token")
.build();
```

Step 4:

```
SellersApi sellersApi = new SellersApi.Builder()
.awsAuthenticationCredentials(awsAuthenticationCredentials)
.lwaAuthorizationCredentials(lwaAuthorizationCredentials)
.awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider(awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider)
.endpoint("https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com")
.build();
```

Issue is at step 4 The class SellersAPI has no method Builder so SellersApi.Builder() is unreslolved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using SellersApi to get the connection with AWS, **you can reference my other answer [Amazon Selling Partner API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361288/amazon-selling-partner-api-request/68504589#68504589) about how to test connection with AWS using Seller Partner API.**

Also, here is the answer how to [Generating a Java client library](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md) below.
Navigate to sellers.json in the selling-partner-api-models\models\sellers-api-model folder of your local copy of the repository.

Copy sellers.json into C:\SwaggerToCL.

Generate the client Library.

```
java -jar C:\SwaggerToCL\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i C:\SwaggerToCL\Sellers.json -l java -o C:\SwaggerToCL\Sellers_JavaCL
```

Then the SellersApi in your package io.swagger.client.api; contains builder like this. 
Anyway, you can just read the code and know the processing about how to connect with AWS.

```
public static class Builder {
    private AWSAuthenticationCredentials awsAuthenticationCredentials;
    private LWAAuthorizationCredentials lwaAuthorizationCredentials;
    private String endpoint;
    private LWAAccessTokenCache lwaAccessTokenCache;
    private Boolean disableAccessTokenCache = false;
    private AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider;

    public Builder awsAuthenticationCredentials(AWSAuthenticationCredentials awsAuthenticationCredentials) {
        this.awsAuthenticationCredentials = awsAuthenticationCredentials;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder lwaAuthorizationCredentials(LWAAuthorizationCredentials lwaAuthorizationCredentials) {
        this.lwaAuthorizationCredentials = lwaAuthorizationCredentials;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder endpoint(String endpoint) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Builder lwaAccessTokenCache(LWAAccessTokenCache lwaAccessTokenCache) {
        this.lwaAccessTokenCache = lwaAccessTokenCache;
        return this;
    }
    
   public Builder disableAccessTokenCache() {
        this.disableAccessTokenCache = true;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Builder awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider(AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider) {
        this.awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider = awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider;
        return this;
    }
    

    public SellersApi build() {
        if (awsAuthenticationCredentials == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("AWSAuthenticationCredentials not set");
        }

        if (lwaAuthorizationCredentials == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("LWAAuthorizationCredentials not set");
        }

        if (StringUtil.isEmpty(endpoint)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Endpoint not set");
        }

        AWSSigV4Signer awsSigV4Signer;
        if ( awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider == null) {
            awsSigV4Signer = new AWSSigV4Signer(awsAuthenticationCredentials);
        }
        else {
            awsSigV4Signer = new AWSSigV4Signer(awsAuthenticationCredentials,awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider);
        }
        
        LWAAuthorizationSigner lwaAuthorizationSigner = null;            
        if (disableAccessTokenCache) {
            lwaAuthorizationSigner = new LWAAuthorizationSigner(lwaAuthorizationCredentials);
        }
        else {
            if (lwaAccessTokenCache == null) {
                lwaAccessTokenCache = new LWAAccessTokenCacheImpl();                  
             }
             lwaAuthorizationSigner = new LWAAuthorizationSigner(lwaAuthorizationCredentials,lwaAccessTokenCache);
        }

        return new SellersApi(new ApiClient()
            .setAWSSigV4Signer(awsSigV4Signer)
            .setLWAAuthorizationSigner(lwaAuthorizationSigner)
            .setBasePath(endpoint));
    }
}
```

Comment: ApiClient also doesnt have those methods. I manually added those fields and appended signing process at the end of the request creation in the ApiClient.java class.

Comment: in ApiClient.buildRequest method, paste these before return: ` request = lwaAuthorizationSigner.sign(request);
        request = awsSigV4Signer.sign(request);`

Answer (score 1):

Add this builder to your SellersApi.java class:

```
public static class Builder {
    private AWSAuthenticationCredentials awsAuthenticationCredentials;
    private LWAAuthorizationCredentials lwaAuthorizationCredentials;
    private String endpoint;
    private LWAAccessTokenCache lwaAccessTokenCache;
    private Boolean disableAccessTokenCache = false;
    private AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider;

    public Builder awsAuthenticationCredentials(AWSAuthenticationCredentials awsAuthenticationCredentials) {
        this.awsAuthenticationCredentials = awsAuthenticationCredentials;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder lwaAuthorizationCredentials(LWAAuthorizationCredentials lwaAuthorizationCredentials) {
        this.lwaAuthorizationCredentials = lwaAuthorizationCredentials;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder endpoint(String endpoint) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Builder lwaAccessTokenCache(LWAAccessTokenCache lwaAccessTokenCache) {
        this.lwaAccessTokenCache = lwaAccessTokenCache;
        return this;
    }
    
  public Builder disableAccessTokenCache() {
        this.disableAccessTokenCache = true;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Builder awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider(AWSAuthenticationCredentialsProvider awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider) {
        this.awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider = awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider;
        return this;
    }
    

    public SellersApi build() {
        if (awsAuthenticationCredentials == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("AWSAuthenticationCredentials not set");
        }

        if (lwaAuthorizationCredentials == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("LWAAuthorizationCredentials not set");
        }

        if (StringUtil.isEmpty(endpoint)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Endpoint not set");
        }

        AWSSigV4Signer awsSigV4Signer;
        if ( awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider == null) {
            awsSigV4Signer = new AWSSigV4Signer(awsAuthenticationCredentials);
        }
        else {
            awsSigV4Signer = new AWSSigV4Signer(awsAuthenticationCredentials,awsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider);
        }
        
        LWAAuthorizationSigner lwaAuthorizationSigner = null;            
        if (disableAccessTokenCache) {
            lwaAuthorizationSigner = new LWAAuthorizationSigner(lwaAuthorizationCredentials);
        }
        else {
            if (lwaAccessTokenCache == null) {
                lwaAccessTokenCache = new LWAAccessTokenCacheImpl();                  
            }
            lwaAuthorizationSigner = new LWAAuthorizationSigner(lwaAuthorizationCredentials,lwaAccessTokenCache);
        }

        return new SellersApi(new ApiClient()
            .setAWSSigV4Signer(awsSigV4Signer)
            .setLWAAuthorizationSigner(lwaAuthorizationSigner)
            .setBasePath(endpoint));
    }
}
```

add `awsSigV4Signer` and `lwaAuthorizationSigner`to ApiClient.java as fields and append those two lines at the end of the `buildRequest` method before return:

```
request = lwaAuthorizationSigner.sign(request);
request = awsSigV4Signer.sign(request);
```